# Подчёркиваются ли союзы, частицы, вводные слова, которые входят в состав обособленных членов?

Tags: синтаксис

Подчёркиваются ли союзы, частицы, вводные слова, которые входят в состав обособленных членов предложения, например причастного оборота?

Comment: Приведите примеры. Что значит подчёркиваются? Вводные слова обособляются.

Comment: Например, волнистой линией, когда они в составе ПчО.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При синтаксическом разборе мы обозначаем с помощью подчёркивания **члены предложения**, а  служебные части речи не являются членами предложения, при  разборе с ними бывают связаны определённые проблемы.

Союзы не являются членами предложения и при соединении однородных членов не выделяются, но в некоторых случаях могут входить в состав неоднословных членов предложения. Во-первых, это сравнительные союзы в составе сравнительных оборотов, например: Гладь залива **была как зеркало**. Во-вторых, это союзы в составе обособленных членов предложения, например: Останавливаясь **часто и надолго**, мы добрались до места только на третьи сутки.

Предлоги также не могут выступать как самостоятельные члены предложения, однако они употребляются в составе предложно-падежной группы, совместно с формой падежа выражая определённое значение. Поэтому **во всех трех комплексах принято подчёркивать предлог вместе с существительным, к которому он относится.** При этом необходимо обратить внимание на случаи, когда предлог и существительное разделены прилагательными или причастиями, например: вместо старшего брата. В этом случае ошибкой будет подчёркивание предлога вместе с прилагательным как определения; подчёркиваем: ***вместо  брата.***

**Формообразующие частицы входят в состав составных глагольных форм и подчёркиваются вместе с глаголом** как при контактном, так и при неконтактном их расположении, например: **Пусть** он мне **позвонит!**

**Смысловые (неформообразующие) частицы членами предложения не являются**, однако в школьной практике отрицательная частица **не** обычно подчёркивается **как единый член предложения вместе с тем словом, к которому она относится**, например: Здесь **не курят**. Я **не очень** рассчитывал на помощь.

**Допустимо невыделение** как предлогов, так и всех смысловых частиц.

Некоторые учителя **для выделения союзов учат обводить их кружком, а предлоги — треугольником. Такое выделение не является общепринятым.**

**Вводные слова и обращения не являются членами предложения.** Иногда учащиеся заключают эти компоненты в квадратные скобки или подчёркивают крестиками (в комплексе Бабайцевой). Это нежелательно, так как подчёркивание используется только для обозначения членов предложения; допустимо отметить эти элементы предложения надписыванием над ними слов «вводное» или «обращение».